# Snap scroll in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am currently working on a horizontal scroll site, the scroll function I have allows horizontal scroll even if using a mouse wheel up and down. However the function makes the scrolling kind of wonky. I have the HTML divided into section tags with each one filling the view of the page. Is there a way I can implement snap scrolling into this JS function to where it snaps to the next  tag on scroll?

```
   const item = document.getElementById("scroll");

   window.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
   if (e.deltaY > 0) item.scrollLeft += 100;
   else item.scrollLeft -= 100;
});
```

Comment: If we assume size of each section is 100px, instead of scroll 100px at a time you should consider position of `scrollLeft` and scroll it to the nearest multiplication of 100. You can also post some html to create a [mre]